# Google Sheets Function For Only High

Tags: google-sheets

Hope You and You're Family Are Safe

Requesting all your guidance on the Google Sheets Function, to take only Yesterday's High Value using Index function. I have tried but getting error.

Please help me on this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlnX1.jpg)

Comment: `Hlookup` or `Query` will be better to use here, I think. If you want a specific answer, please show the exact formula you are using as it is very hard to read in your image. Your image also does not show column names.

Comment: Try to share a Google Sheet sample sharable link, so we can see what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Apparently you are parsing a json, you can just choose a the high value (key = High) and probably the day ... give us the origin of data.

Answer (score 0):

try with semicolons like:

```
=INDEX(E2:J3; 2; 3)
```